# Как получить размер массива переданный через указатель?

Tags: c, массивы, указатели

Есть код:

```
void LongestWord(char* sen[]) {
    // Find & print longest word
}

int main(int argc, char* argv[]) {
    // Disable stdout buffering
    setvbuf(stdout, NULL, _IONBF, 0);

    // Keep this function call here
    LongestWord(gets(stdin));

    return 0;
}
```

Задача: Как в функции `LongestWord()` вычислить количество элементов `sen[]`?
 Насколько мне известно, через указатель вычислить нельзя. Обычно в таких случаях размер массива передается вместе с типом `size_t`. Этот код из [coderbyte](https://www.coderbyte.com/).

Может я что то не догоняю?

Comment: 1. Никак. 2. Этот код даже не скомпилируется.

Comment: скажу по другому, а зачем у main есть argc, который определяет кол-во элементов в argv?

Comment: Почему не скомпилируется? Это задача за ресурса Coderbyte. Вот ссылка: https://www.coderbyte.com/editor/guest:Longest%20Word:C

Comment: Потому что error C2664: gets: невозможно преобразовать параметр 1 из "FILE *" в "char *"

Comment: Присоединяюсь в @MSDN.WhiteKnight: `gets()` принимает в качестве аргумента не сам поток (эта функция и так прибита к `stdin`), а выходной буфер, в который буде извлечено содержимое этого потока до ближайшего символа перевода строки.

Comment: Вывод: не надо слепо верить авторитетам. Даже они могут ошибаться.

Comment: Тут ошибка на ошибке. Во-первых, `gets(stdin)`. Во-вторых, `gets` возвращает `char *`, а  `LongestWord` хочет `char **`. В-третьих, нет уже давно в С никакого `gets`. По вашей ссылке на coderbyte написан просто вопиющий гамнокод.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

(Правильное определение: `void LongestWord(char sen[])`, без звёздочки, как массив знаков.)

`sen` - это *специальный* массив, именно *строка в Си*.

(sen = sentence, т.е. предложение.)

Так как строки в Си *заканчиваются бинарным нулем* (символом `\0`), нет проблемы в определении её длины (= размеру массива `sen`) - это просто количество символов до первого появления символа `\0`.

Но вам это даже не надо делать вручную, потому что это делает стандартная функция `strlen()` (string's length - длина строки).

Comment: Вообще-то там передается указатель на указатель `char* sen[]`, т.е. массив, думаю.

Comment: Да, это массив указателей, никакая это не строка.

Comment: @LLENN, `sen` безусловно **есть** строка. Вы можете удалить звёздочку из описания параметра или сохранить её, всё равно. Строка - это массив символов, а голое имя массива - это *указатель на его первый элемент*. Всё равно, если вы прибавите звёздочку перед это имя в описании параметра, или нет.

Comment: @Djasir, см. мой комментарий для LLEEN-a.

Comment: Я дико извиняюсь но чем тогда отличается этот char* sen[] от char* argv[] ? В sen строка т.е. через sen[i] можно получить строку по символьно а в argv[i] по строчно. Или здесь в sen[i] специально по "урезали" строки чтобы каждый указатель указывал только на один символ? Т.е. вставил в конце бинарный нуль? Можете указать ссылку на графическое разъяснение этой темы?

Comment: @Djasir, я сформулировал этот факт как новый вопрос [Различное определение параметра, тот же самый результат](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/q/848379/233990).

Comment: @Djasir, я извиняюсь вам, вы прав. Благодаря вам я исправил мой ответ.

Comment: @LLENN, я извиняюсь вам, вы прав (см. другие комментарии). Благодаря вам я исправил мой ответ.

Comment: @MarianD: Я рад что вы поняли свою ошибку, но понять ее можно было без вашего вопроса, просто прочитав что такое указатель на массив не являющийся ссылкой на строку.

Answer (score 0):

В плюсах, в отличие от C, есть возможность узнать размер массива при передаче его в шаблон по ссылке:

```
template<std::size_t N> char *LongestWord(char *(&text)[N]);
```

Comment: Задачу надо решить на Си)

Comment: А. Ну тогда либо передавать отдельным аргументом размер массива, либо _обязательно_ ставить последним элементом sentinel, как нулевой символ в конце строки, например. В паре argc-argv применяют оба способа: `argv[argc] == NULL`.