# Различное определение параметра, тот же самый результат

Tags: c

Какая разница между определением параметра как

```
char * sentence[]
```

и

```
char sentence[]
```

когда получится тот же самый результат после вызова функции?

```
#include  <stdio.h>

void function1(char * sentence[]) { 
    printf("%s", sentence); 
}

void function2(char sentence[]) { 
    printf("%s", sentence); 
}


int main(void)
{
    function1("Hello, world!\n");
    function2("Hello, world!\n");
    return 0;
}
```

Вывод:

> ```
> Hello, world!
> Hello, world!
> ```

Comment: В первом вызове ваш код порождает неопределенное поведение. "Тот же самый результат" - не более чем проявление этого неопределенного поведения

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Тут сыграла роль возможность неявного приведения несовместимых типов указателей, работающая в некоторых компиляторах Си, без явного на то указания.

Собственно, при компилировании [выводятся предупреждения](https://wandbox.org/permlink/wEEmBOWDSZIdIdnz):

> ```
> prog.c: In function 'function1':
> prog.c:4:14: warning: format '%s' expects argument of type 'char *', but argument 2 has type 'char **' [-Wformat=]
>      printf("%s", sentence);
>              ~^   ~~~~~~~~
> prog.c: In function 'main':
> prog.c:13:15: warning: passing argument 1 of 'function1' from incompatible pointer type [-Wincompatible-pointer-types]
>      function1("Hello, world!\n");
>                ^~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
> prog.c:3:23: note: expected 'char **' but argument is of type 'char *'
>  void function1(char * sentence[]) {
>                 ~~~~~~~^~~~~~~~~~
> ```

говорящие о том, что тип аргумента фактически не соответствует строковому параметру, т.к. указатель на указатель на `char`, это не тоже самое, что просто указатель на `char`.

Правильно использовать второй вариант, или, что то же самое использовать в  `char * sentence` в сигнатуре.

Comment: Я так понял, по стандарту в первом случае должна была быть ошибка. Если для GCC добавить флажок `-pedantic-errors`, [warning превращается в error](https://godbolt.org/g/J8EMpn).

Comment: В С нет возможности неявного приведения произвольных указателей. Это не более чем особенность конкретного компилятора + невнимательность пользователя, проигнорировавшего диагностические сообщения.

Comment: @HolyBlackCat: В стандарте нет понятия "ошибка", а есть лишь требование выдачи диагностического сообщения. Даже без `-pedantic-errors` диагностическое сообщение будет честно выдано GCC. Это просто автор вопроса его проигнорировал. Вот для таких игнорирующих и полезен `-pedantic-errors`.

Comment: @AnT упомянутый код компилируется не только в gcc, но и в [clang](http://rextester.com/EMH93921), и в [msvc](http://rextester.com/JSHL44650). Так что про особенность конкретного компилятора несколько странно слышать. Более того из с11 п. 6.3.2.3/7: *"A pointer to an object type may be converted to a pointer to a different object type."*. Если у Вас есть иная информация, дайте, пожалуйста, ссылку.

Comment: @alexolut: Во-первых, в С и С++ нет понятия "компилируется" или "не компилируется". Имеет значение именно и только наличие стандартных *диагностических сообщений*. Во-вторых, 6.3.2.3/7 говорит о том, что можно выполнить *явный каст*, но 6.3.2.3/7 ни слова не говорит о том, что такое преобразование может делаться *неявно*. За правилами выполнения (или не выполнения) *неявных* преобразований в 6.3/1 читатель отсылается  в 6.5 для каждого оператора отдельно. Сразу скажу, что согласно 6.5 такие неявные преобразования в С не делаются никогда.

Comment: И, в-третьих, для того, чтобы наконец окончательно закрыть эту тему в С99 в раздел 6.5.4/3 было специально добавлено "Conversions that involve pointers, other than where permitted by the constraints of 6.5.16.1, shall be specified **by means of an explicit cast**." Вопреки расхожей легенде, правила контроля типов указателей в С ничем не отличаются и никогда не отличались от С++, кроме преобразования из `void *` и ряда других мелочей. В С нет неявной конверсии `char *` в `char **`.

Comment: А компиляторы, которые это "не будут компилировать" найдутся быстро: навскидку Pelles и TinyC. Не говоря уже о том, что в режиме строгого контроля ошибок `-pedantic-errors` это не пропустит ни GCC, ни Clang. Вы просто использовали их в режиме "псевдо-С суржика". Включите режим настоящего С - и картина поменяется.

Comment: @AnT спасибо за разъяснения!