# Язык C, MinGW, несовпадение типа аргумента функции

Tags: c, mingw

Столкнулся с непонятным предупреждением компилятора.

Рассмотрим два случая.

1) Корректный случай:

```
void func(const void *_data);
void *data;
func(data);
```

2) Предупреждение компилятора о несоответствии типов:

```
void func(const void **_data);
void **data;
func(data);
// note: expected 'const void **' but argument is of type 'void **'
```

Почему компилятор ругается? 
Может ли это быть внутренним багом компилятора?

Comment: потому что массивы не указатели, хотя и пытаются под них мимикрировать.

Comment: Возможный дубликат вопроса: [Различное определение параметра, тот же самый результат](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/848379/%d0%a0%d0%b0%d0%b7%d0%bb%d0%b8%d1%87%d0%bd%d0%be%d0%b5-%d0%be%d0%bf%d1%80%d0%b5%d0%b4%d0%b5%d0%bb%d0%b5%d0%bd%d0%b8%d0%b5-%d0%bf%d0%b0%d1%80%d0%b0%d0%bc%d0%b5%d1%82%d1%80%d0%b0-%d1%82%d0%be%d1%82-%d0%b6%d0%b5-%d1%81%d0%b0%d0%bc%d1%8b%d0%b9-%d1%80%d0%b5%d0%b7%d1%83%d0%bb%d1%8c%d1%82%d0%b0%d1%82)

Comment: *"Может ли это быть внутренним багом компилятора?"* Наивная мысль. :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

В языке С не существует неявного приведения типа от `T **` к `const T **`. Потому компилятор и ругается. Правила константой корректности языка С допускают "появление" `const` на первом уровне индирекции, но на более глубоких уровнях все `const` должны в точности совпадать

```
void *p = 0;
const void *pc = p; // Можно

void **pp = 0;
const void **ppc = pp; // Нельзя

const void **pcp = 0;
const void *const *pcpc = pcp; // Можно
```

Собственно, именно это вы уже и проиллюстрировали своим примером. Ваша функция требует параметр типа `const void **`, а вы передаете туда `void **`. Это ошибка. Никакого "бага компилятора" тут нет.

---

В языке С++ правила константной корректности существенно отличаются: разрешается добавлять `const` на любом уровне индирекции, если одновременно добавляются `const` на всех уровнях до самого верхнего уровня индирекции

```
void **pp = 0;
const void *const *pcpc = pp; // Можно в С++, но нельзя в С
```

То есть в вашем примере в С++ прошел бы такой вариант

```
void func(const void *const *_data);
void **data;
func(data);
```

Но не в С.

Comment: Понял, спасибо. Где можно почитать про тонкости в таких моментах? В Стандарте, или есть русскоязычные источники?

Answer (score 0):

Языку разрешается аргументу **Type** const * **Pointer** присваивать тип **Type** * . А типы разные. `void const *` * <>  `void *` * . Можно так : `void * const` * == `void *` * .